# I can't insert both values in different SQL tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I used this code for my controller to insert values into tables.

```
public boolean createDuty() throws ParseException{

    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery; 

    db.getConnection();     

    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO duty(dutyName)" + " VALUES ('" + dutyName + "')";
    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO venue(venueAddress)" + " VALUES ('" + venueAddress + "')";

        if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
            success = true;
        }

    db.terminate();

    return success;
}
```

However, the output from java only says that only the venueAddress has been inserted and not the dutyName.

```
Successfully connected to jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/xxxxx.
DB Query: INSERT INTO venue(venueAddress) VALUES ('Woodgrove Tennis Centre')
Connection is closed
```

Is there something wrong with my codes? Can someone pls help me..

Comment: You are doing a second assignment to `dbQuery`, not a concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your code:

```
dbQuery = "INSERT INTO duty(dutyName)" + " VALUES ('" + dutyName + "')";
```

Here you're assigning a SQL query to the variable `dbQuery`. Then

```
dbQuery = "INSERT INTO venue(venueAddress)" + " VALUES ('" + venueAddress + "')";
```

Here you're assigning another SQL query to the same variable. Then

```
if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
```

Here you're executing the query referenced by `dbQuery`. If you want to execute 2 queries, you need to call `db.updateRequest()` twice once with the first SQL query, and once with the second one.

Also, read about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and will break as soon as `venueAddress` or `dutyName` contains a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

you only execute the second query:

change:

```
dbQuery = "INSERT INTO duty(dutyName)" + " VALUES ('" + dutyName + "')";
dbQuery = "INSERT INTO venue(venueAddress)" + " VALUES ('" + venueAddress + "')";

    if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
        success = true;
    }
```

to:

```
dbQuery = "INSERT INTO duty(dutyName)" + " VALUES ('" + dutyName + "');";
dbQuery += "INSERT INTO venue(venueAddress)" + " VALUES ('" + venueAddress + "')";

    if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
        success = true;
    }
```

You have to add a ";" ad end of statement one.
Also you have to concat both strings.